# Pegar dados retorno xml

Tags: c#, xml

Estou tentando retornar os dados deste xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<GerarNfseResposta xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
    <ListaMensagemRetorno>
        <MensagemRetorno>
            <Codigo>00000</Codigo>
            <Mensagem>00000 - O RPS 8964 da série 999 já foi informado em outra nota fiscal.</Mensagem>
        </MensagemRetorno>
    </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</GerarNfseResposta>
```

Estou tentando fazer desta forma:

```
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
xmlResponse.LoadXml(soapResult);
XmlNode responseNode = xmlResponse.LastChild.LastChild.FirstChild;

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlResponse.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws");
XmlNode codigo = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Codigo", ns);
XmlNode mensagem = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Mensagem", ns);
```

Porém o código e mensagem sempre vem null.

Eu tentei desta forma abaixo:

```
 string soapResult = string.Empty;

        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        xmlResponse.LoadXml(soapResult);
        XNamespace ns = XNamespace
.Get("http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws");

         soapResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(soapResult,
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult)
                .Descendants(ns + "ListaMensagemRetorno")
                .Elements(ns + "MensagemRetorno")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Codigo = x.Element(ns + "Codigo")?.Value,
                    Mensagem = x.Element(ns + "Mensagem")?.Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

Porém também não foi válido, tentei tirando essa linha
`soapResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(soapResult,
                System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));` porém vem `null`

Tentei pegar desta forma também e não deu certo:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode Gerar = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("GerarNfseResposta"); System.Xml.XmlNode ListaMensagemRetorno = Gerar.SelectSingleNode("ListaMensagemRetorno"); System.Xml.XmlNode MensagemRetorno = ListaMensagemRetorno.SelectSingleNode("MensagemRetorno")
```

Tentei desta forma abaixo também, porém sempre vem null.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xmlResponse.SelectNodes("/GerarNfseResposta/ListaMensagemRetorno/MensagemRetorno");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string firstName = xn["Codigo"].InnerText;
            string lastName = xn["Mensagem"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
        }
```

Retorno XML:

```
 <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><ns2:GerarNfseResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"><return>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?&gt;
&lt;GerarNfseResposta xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"&gt;
    &lt;ListaMensagemRetorno&gt;
        &lt;MensagemRetorno&gt;
            &lt;Codigo&gt;00000&lt;/Codigo&gt;
            &lt;Mensagem&gt;00000 - O RPS 8965 da série 999 já foi informado em outra nota fiscal.&lt;/Mensagem&gt;
        &lt;/MensagemRetorno&gt;
    &lt;/ListaMensagemRetorno&gt;
&lt;/GerarNfseResposta&gt;
</return></ns2:GerarNfseResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Comment: esse XML da pergunta contem problemas, é difícil reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic esse xml é o que webservice me retorna.

Comment: Então o formato dele é inválido ... !!!

Comment: Eu não consigo pegar o retorno dele ?

Comment: Um exemplo do problema, uma tag: que é do topo `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>` de qualquer arquivo xml, está no meio...
Tem como pegar esse cara pelo endereço, edita e coloque na sua pergunta.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta com o retorno correto, desculpe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é com [XDocument do namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2) [System.Xml.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2), ***exemplo***:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace
    .Get("http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"); 

string soapResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"./data.xml", 
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult, LoadOptions.None)
        .Descendants(ns + "ListaMensagemRetorno")
        .Elements(ns + "MensagemRetorno")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Codigo = x.Element(ns + "Codigo")?.Value,
            Mensagem = x.Element(ns + "Mensagem")?.Value
        })
        .ToList();
```

Lembrando que qualquer [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) que possui um `namespace` para recuperar suas informações também deve ser passado. Outro fator é que esse [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) tem o `enconding` `ISO-8859-1` que precisa ser respeitado e no seu carregamento também deve ser configurado, sendo responsável pelos acentos e caracteres especiais.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Parsing XML using XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798852/parsing-xml-using-xdocument)
- [how to give encoding as ISO-8859-1 in xml created using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139127/how-to-give-encoding-as-iso-8859-1-in-xml-created-using-linq)
- [Linq-to-XML with XDocument namespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555609/linq-to-xml-with-xdocument-namespace-issue)
- [Parsing Xml in C#](https://coderwall.com/p/qghcqw/parsing-xml-in-c)

Comment: Consegui descodificar, porém ele me retorna este erro: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 196.

Comment: Eu tive que fazer um replace nesta linha `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>` e ai deu certo. Obrigado.